# Problem with queue in combination with thread between different processes

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, queue

I am using queues in the context of processes and threads and there is a constellation with a strange behavior which i do not understand.

the used queue is defined like this: multiprocessing.Queue(1)

**First Constellation (works fine)**

1. initiate queue
2. Process 1 starts Process 2 (queue in parameters)
3. Process 1 starts Thread

2 Loops (one inside Thread one in Process 2) are communcating via the queue: everything works fine

[image: constellation 1]

**Second Constellation (does not work)**

1. Process 1 starts Process 2
2. inside Process 2 queue is initiated
3. Process 2 starts Process 3 (queue in parameters)
4. Process 2 starts Thread

2 Loops (one inside Thread one in Process 3) are communcating via the queue: 
--> Loop in Thread in Process2 says always queue is full (wants to put something in the queue)
--> Loop in Process 3 says always queue is empty

[image: constellation 2]

**Third Constellation (works fine)**

1. Process 1 starts Process 2
2. inside Process 2 queue is initiated
3. Process 2 starts Process 3 (queue in parameters)

2 Loops (one in Process 2 one in Process 3) are communcating via the queue: everything works fine

[image: constellation 3]

I do not understand what's the problem with the second constellation. I read that this could happen if one first starts the thread and then the child-process. But i start Process 3 first and then start the Thread in Process 2. And if the thread is the Problem why does constellation 1 work?

Comment: Why do you want to mix threads and processes? Is there a benefit in speed for your application?

Comment: There is no real benefit from mixing, i now use only processes. But i want to understand why it does not work (I came across this constellation more randomly). This question is more for my education than for real code.